# Need help with regex for pick list where there are similar values between semi colons

Tags: regular-expressions

This is racking my brain!  In apex, I need to determine whether or not a specific sub-string is in a picklists value.  So I'm trying to use the `Matcher`class and the `find()` method using regex.  My problem is that I can't figure out the regex I need.  So, here is an example :

Need to determine if a string like `'Sales Manager'` is in : `'Associate;Assistant Sales Manager;Regional Sales Manager;HR Manager'`.

The result for the list above would be `false`.

But `true` here:

`'Sales Manager'` is in : `'Associate;Assistant Sales Manager;Sales Manager;Regional Sales Manager;HR Manager'`

I tried `\\\bSales Manager\\\b` but that's not it.  Sales manager is normally a variable that I need to search.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You can use this also - contains(substring)...Which returns true if specified String found in the string.

Comment: He would have to be careful with that as it would return `true` because "Sales Manager" is a substring of "Assistant Sales Manager" as well.

Comment: Yeah contains doesn't work, due to the similar values.  That is what I had first and noticed other types were getting flagged as true!  :P

Answer (score 0):

How about this - `(^Sales Manager)|(;Sales Manager)`

Try it here (http://regexr.com/3c1hs) against this string: `Sales Manager;Associate;Assistant Sales Manager;Sales Manager;Regional Sales Manager;HR Manager;Sales Manager`

It finds the `Sales Manager` if it's the first in the string, last or in the middle.

Usage sample:

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile('(^Sales Manager)|(;Sales Manager)');

Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher('Associate;Assistant Sales Manager;Sales Manager;Regional Sales Manager;HR Manager');

//myMatcher.find() returns TRUE if it finds a match
System.assert(myMatcher.find());
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll give that a shot and flag this if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the ideas, I ended up using a the split method with a regex of .split('[;]{1}'); and then iterated through the array looking for a match!